# BASH / sed - not giving same output for simple sed commands

Tags: linux, bash, sed, debian, darwin

Box 1:  **uname -srm**

```
Darwin 16.1.0 x86_64
```

Box 2: **uname -srm; cat /etc/debian_version**

```
Linux 3.13.0-100-generic x86_64
jessie/sid
```

BASH on box1 is: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)

BASH on box2 is: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

On both boxes, I'm have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

args="$@"
cust="$(echo ${args} | sed "s/^[, \t][, \t]*//;s/[, \t][, \t]*$//;s/[ ,][ ,]*/|/g;s/^/^/;s/$/$/;s/|/$|^/g;s/|/\n/g"|sort|uniq|tr '\012' '|'|sed "s/|$//")";
echo --1 ${cust}

cust="$(echo ${args} | sed "s/^[, \t][, \t]*//;s/[, \t][, \t]*$//; \
        s/[ ,][ ,]*/|/g; \
        s/^/^/;s/$/$/; \
        s/|/$|^/g; \
        s/|/\n/g" | sort | uniq | tr '\012' '|' \
        | sed "s/|$//")";
echo --2 ${cust}

cust="$(echo ${args}   | sed "s/^[, \t][, \t]*//;s/[, \t][, \t]*$//")"
cust="$(echo ${cust}   | sed "s/[ ,][ ,]*/|/g")"
cust="$(echo ${cust}   | sed "s/^/^/;s/$/$/")"
cust="$(echo ${cust}   | sed "s/|/$|^/g")"
cust="$(echo ${cust}   | sed "s/|/\n/g")"
cust="$(echo "${cust}" | sort | uniq | tr '\012' '|')"
cust="$(echo ${cust}   | sed "s/|$//")";
echo --3 ${cust}
```

All commands are same. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
## Remove prefix/suffix space, commas.
## Replce inbetween spaces/commas with '|'.
## Prefix '^' & suffix '$' in the regex value.
## Embedd strict regex pattern for a customer by
## - replacing: '|' with '$|^'
## Sort & Uniq - for alphabetical order & remove duplicates.
## Set ${cust} regex variable with a valid regex value.
## Ex1: ".*" (if no argument is passed i.e. for all IDs).
## Ex2: "^custID1$|^custID2$|^custID3$"
##      (if 'custID1 custID3, custID2' were passed)
```

On box1: When I'm running the script with arguments: **aa1, aa3,aa2   aa1 , a0**, I'm getting the following output which is *NOT* what I'm expecting in the output (Character '**n**' is getting embedded here and it didn't even do *sort* or *uniq* operation on the values):

```
$ ./1.sh aa1, aa3,aa2   aa1 , a0

--1 ^aa1$n^aa3$n^aa2$n^aa1$n^a0$
--2 ^aa1$n^aa3$n^aa2$n^aa1$n^a0$
--3 ^aa1$n^aa3$n^aa2$n^aa1$n^a0$
```

On box2: When I'm doing the same: I'm getting the EXPECTED output.

```
--1 ^a0$|^aa1$|^aa2$|^aa3$
--2 ^a0$|^aa1$|^aa2$|^aa3$
--3 ^a0$|^aa1$|^aa2$|^aa3$
```

What should I change so that the above expression gives same output on both machines? OR- do I have to update BASH on box1?

My understanding is, that I'm doing very simple sed operation and both BASH versions should have given me same output for such simple sed commands.

Comment: use -e option for echo commands (-e : enable interpretation of backslash escapes)

Comment: Please show exactly how you execute the command — as code.  Is it `sh script aa1, aa3,aa2 aa1 , a0` or `bash script aa1, aa3,aa2 aa1 , a0` or something else?  Are you sure you're passing commas?  Commas surrounded by spaces?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler updated my question.

Comment: Thanks — it is clearer.  Which shebang line do you have in `1.sh`?  Do you have `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` or do you omit it?  It might matter because `/bin/sh` is used in the absence of a shebang — and `/bin/sh` is not necessarily identical to `/bin/bash`.  Also, am I right in interpreting the script as containing three equivalent ways of writing the same operations?

Comment: @A.M.D I don't think I'm using -e or want to use -e with echo command. Can you clarify where I would need it actually? Variable args gets "aa1, aa3,aa2   aa1 , a0" in it and the commands in the script are just massaging the special charaters using simple sed / tr commands. As you see, on box2, I'm getting the valid output and I'm not using echo -e option at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's correct. All three commands are doing the same thing. It's a LONG line vs shorter line (Linting thing you know). I updated my script part, it's #!/bin/bash

Comment: In the middle script, all the backslashes except the one before the final `sed` are optional.  The one before the final `sed` could be replaced by a `|` and the `|` at the start of the next line deleted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Tried the above comment but it got me the same output. But your answer below, worked perfectly even with args="$@". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit convoluted to add pipes, then remove them, then add them back again.  This code works on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (Darwin 16.1.0) — I believe it would work on Linux too:

```
#!/bin/bash

args="$*"
IFS=$' \t,'
# echo $args

cust="$(printf '%s\n' ${args} |
        sort -u |
        tr '\012' '|' | 
        sed -e 's/|$//' -e 's/^|//' -e 's/^/^/' -e 's/$/$/' -e 's/|/$|^/g')"
echo "--2 ${cust}"
```

The combination of setting `IFS` so it includes a comma and passing `$args` to `printf` without any quotes around it eliminates oddities in the spacing and commas.  Sorting uniquely can be done in one operation.  Then replace all the newlines with `|` symbols, then use `sed` to remove any leading or trailing `|`, add the leading `^` and trailing `$` and the intermediate `$|^` sequences.  Then echo the result string.

When the script is made executable and called `x37.sh`, it produces:

```
$ ./x37.sh aa1, aa3,aa2 aa1 , a0
--2 ^a0$|^aa1$|^aa2$|^aa3$
$
```

There are ways to do without the `tr` command, making `sed` do the line concatenation.

Comment: :) Except it didn't cover one thing. If I pass `./1.sh ,   ,     ,aa1, aa3,aa2   aa1 , a0 ,, ,,` then the above snippet won't work but I guess, I got the hint.

Comment: Use backticks around code in comments so it becomes more legible, please.  You can edit comments for 5 minutes.

Comment: As revised (remove leading `|` too), I think it works for your second case.

Comment: To put IFS value back after $cust variable is set, should I do: `IFS=$''` or `IFS=$' '`?

Comment: I'd use `savedIFS="$IFS"` before, and `IFS="$savedIFS"` after.  Alternatively: `IFS=$' \t\n'` should reset it to the official default (see [Word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) in the manual).